# React to a reaction to get a role (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I have this code that supposes to give roles when reacting to the message with specific emoji.

```
message.channel.send('Message')
.then(function (message) {
  message.react("0️⃣")
});
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return reaction.emoji.name === '0️⃣' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector();

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === '0️⃣') role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Test Role");
  message.member.addRole(role);
});
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: You used `user.id === message.author.id` in your filter, in that way this filter will only listen to the bot reactions seen that the message.author is the bot itself

Comment: Also I just realised you are not even using that filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter isn't correct. You only need to check if the reaction is the correct one.

I've edited your code by replacing the message variable name to msg. msg defines the message sent. The message where you need to listen to reactions.

Then adapt your filter, and include your whole code inside the if bracket.

```js
message.channel.send('Message').then(msg => {
  msg.react("0️⃣")
  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '0️⃣';
  };

  const collector = msg.createReactionCollector();

  collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '0️⃣'){
       role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Test Role");
       message.member.addRole(role);
    }
  });
});
```